# Options for converting incoming emails into POST requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, imap

Currently we're converting emails into POST requests using Sendgrid's Parse API, but we find this is unreliable, with sometimes emails apparently being delivered but never posted etc. I'd like to have more control over the end-to-end process as it's an enterprise application. What are our options for guaranteeing delivery into our application? Happy to take control of the inbound mail processing ourselves, if there's an easy way.

Comment: You should take this up with Sendgrid, if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar. The mechanics involve setting up an incoming mail server that will accept email, using `Postfix`, and write a custom Postfix filter that will dump each email out to disk. Then write a ruby script that runs periodically that will post the email content out to where-ever you define. So that's one option...

Comment: That seems in-elegant from a maintenance point of view. Might be better doing periodic IMAP requests from Rails to the email server, as the documentation suggests.

Comment: That's another way too - something like http://railspikes.com/2007/6/1/rails-email-processing ?